# Material UI card won't be display as flex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
<Container maxWidth="md">
                <Grid container spacing={4}>
                    <Grid item container xs={12} sm={6} md={4} >
                        <Card variant="outlined" className={classes.card}>
                            <img src={flag} alt="" />
                            <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                                <h2>{name}</h2>
                                <h3>{capital}</h3>
                                <p>{area}</p>
                            </CardContent>
                            <Button size="small" color="primary" variant="contained" onClick={() => handleClick(name)}>
                                Show More Details
                            </Button>
                        </Card>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Container>
```

this codes results card elements as block but I want to show them as display flex but it does not
working

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achive?

Comment: and what the styling you give to the card with classes.card ?